# Will /sbin/nologin Protect Apache from Bash Exploit CVE-2014-6271

Tags: apache, webserver

It was announced widely today (September 24, 2014) that it is possible to manipulate environment variables to execute approximately arbitrary code on *nix systems where Bash is the default shell.  http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/650

Per the article above, CGI scripts are a major attack vector because CGI variables attached to a URL are presented to the Common Gateway Interface as environment variables, *i.e.* the server process (Apache in my case) puts the CGI parameters into the environment.

On my particular installation, Apache has a default shell of /sbin/nologin/ although the default system shell is /bin/bash.

Can such a system be exploited in the manner described?  Alternatively, how can I test it?

(I know I need to replace the Bash shell ASAP; that turns out to be a big deal because of some customization.)

(If this should be migrated to ServerFault, please do so; I put it here because the question is specific to web server programs, and especially Apache.)

Edit: Not the answer, but it may help others; it looks like disabling mod_cgi will mitigate the problem, at least somewhat. https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/24/bash-specially-crafted-environment-variables-code-injection-attack/

Comment: This question is actually more suited for [InfoSec.SE site](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions). Disabling mod_cgi may cause your server to stop working. And also, `nologin` does not solve this problem.

Comment: I sort-of lurk over there, and I'm not sure it is.  This is a question with a really-really specific answer.

Comment: I've disabled mod_cgi.  Server still works.  What would *not* work is anything that used the actual CGI interface to load a program.  I don't have any of that.  Do you have a citation or test that shows that using `/sbin/nologin` doesn't help?  That would be a really valuable answer to this question.

Comment: I don't have a test or citation. The purpose of `nologin` in `/etc/passwd` file is to prevent non-root user from signing into the system using the credential of apache, for example. Since apache is already _in_ the system, it does not need to sign in to run a CGI bash script. What it needs is just the `execute` permission to run.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security and is better suited at the security [SE site which already is discussing this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68146/how-do-i-secure-apache-against-the-bash-shellshock-vulnerability).

Comment: This is a real mess folks. Just posted a question here: http://superuser.com/questions/817802/still-vulnerable-with-ubuntu-14-04-1-and-bash-4-3-7ubuntu1-4-what-next Still vulnerable and fully updated!!

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `/sbin/nologin` as the login shell for the Apache user does not prevent Apache from launching bash.  It only prevents logins with the user that is meant to only run the webserver.

You might be interested in [How do I secure Apache against the Bash Shellshock vulnerability?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68146/how-do-i-secure-apache-against-the-bash-shellshock-vulnerability) from the security StackExchange site.  It suggests some workarounds like running apache in a chroot environment with a patched version of bash.  Even if you can't replace bash everywhere, you might be able to do so for Apache.